# Why is permission denied during pssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell-scripting

I am trying to add an ssh public key to a bunch of servers authorized_keys file. My thought was to use pssh and a list of hosts. To test, I tried to pssh to one host:

```
pssh -i -H root@host echo mypublickeyasastring >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When I run this, I get:

```
-bash: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
```

If, from the same server I run pssh, I just ssh into the host `ssh root@host`, I get in okay and I can run `echo mypublickeyasastring >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` just fine.

I've been skimming the pssh man page but I can't seem to find anything. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you though of using `ssh-copy-id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output redirection is happening on the local machine. You need to quote the command to protect the >>.

Comment: do you mean that I need to do `pssh ... "echo mypublickeyasastring >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"`