# Why is my shell command not working?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell-scripting

I have a shell script that I'm working on that uses pssh to get the user id of a user on a remote server:

```
for USER in $(cat users.txt); do
    runuser -l mike -c 'pssh -H server.mike.com -o /home/mike/output id -u $USER'
    cat /home/mike/output/server.mike.com
```

The file users.txt contains one line

```
mikeghen
```

When I run my script, I get an error:

```
[1] 14:23:15 [FAILURE] server.mike.com Exited with error code 1\
```

But, when I run the command:

```
runuser -l mike -c 'pssh -H server.mike.com -o /home/mike/output id -u mikeghen'
```

I don't get the error:

```
[1] 13:11:53 [SUCCESS] server.mike.com
```

I feel like this has something to do with a question I asked before, [Why is permission denied during pssh?](https://serverfault.com/questions/657965/why-is-permission-denied-during-pssh), and so I tried wrapping my command in quotes with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `''` quotes prevent variable interpolation. Use `""` instead.

```
host:~ sven$ echo $USER
sven
host:~ sven$ echo '$USER'
$USER
host:~ sven$ echo "$USER"
sven
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. A suggestion for anyone else reading this: running your script using `bash -x`